# references for text boxes and other form controls in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I had a web application in visual studio and wanted to work on it.So i just copied all the project folders into an empty web application so i could work.But i am getting lost of errors related to references.

I added all the dlls in the bin folder into the references. Some of the errors reduced but now i am getting errors for all text boxes, drop down boxes i.e all form controls saying the name "" does not exist in the current context when i build the solution.

I tried adding system.windows.form to the reference folder but still its giving the same errors.Is is regarding references or something else? What is suppose to be done?
[image]

Comment: Never heard of "system.windows.form". If you mean "System.Windows.Forms", this referes to WinForms which is form the Windows Desktop, not for the web.

Comment: Did you copy the entire the folder from location to another in Win Explorer or you just copy/paste the code from 1 application to another?? Plz share some screen-shots and error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It mean they are not appearing in the designer as you coped them. You have to delete the  controls and add them so that they can appear in the designer too

Hope this helps